# Converting WebApp into Desktop Application [Java]

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've been writing this very easy Webapp. It receives two parameters, a word and a letter. It counts how many times the letter can be found in said word.

I have a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with the following:
OccurencesCounter.java : has the method count with two params: word and letter. it returns the count (amount of times letter found)
OccurencesServlet.java In here I create an OccurencesCounter obj, I get the params, I call the function count etc, and I forwards request/response to result.jsp
result.jsp I show the results I've calculated.

This has been done for an exercice on Parameters and MVC.
According to the MVC pattern, I can change this webapp easily in a desktop application.
I know i need to change my view, result.jsp.

I need a main class. The rest of the code should stay the same.

My question is the following: What do I use the servlet for? I can't fathom how I could still need it.

I think I can use JOptionPane to input my parameters ("HelloWorld" , "o"), but bypass the servlet alltogether. I'd just need the OccurencesCounter class and my main class.

Is this normal? Or should I use the servlet (in some unknown way to me).

I'm confused, as this is an assignment telling me: We only want you to adjust the view when you create a desktop application, as it is requested by the MVC pattern. Make sure you have one model that works for both assignments.

Thank you

Comment: `I need a main class. The rest of the code should stay the same.` Sorry but no. You should develop the GUI using whatever framework you wish. If you have properly designed your program, you will be able to reuse your data model and business logic, but the GUI will need to be redone.

Answer (score 0):

A [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) listens to http requests and executes Java code, if the requests url matches the servlet mapping. This is useful when working with HTTP (server side/web application) but not in a desktop application (event driven).

> We only want you to adjust the **view** (not your class) when you create a desktop
>   application, as it is requested by the MVC pattern.

They want you to *reuse* your OccurencesCounter class in both environments. Thats always possible, if that class does **not include** any kind of technique, related to the environment, for example a Servlet.

> Make sure you have one model that works for both assignments.

Actually, you class is not a "model", from MVCs point of view. Its more of a service, that can **be called** ([delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29)) by a controller, returning the result (model) and displaying it on any kind of view.

So just create a class with a main method and run your OccurencesCounter class from there.

Comment: Stefan, this means in this context I would indeed only need 2 classes ie OccurencesCouner and OccurencesCounterApp.

I think I got confused about needing to use a Controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the MVC pattern in you web application you should have :

- Model : a set of service, dao, and business classes that will be reused in the desktop application
- Controller : a set of servlet (or controllers if you used a framework) -> al that is UI related and have to be rewritten
- View : a set of HTML, JSP, CSS, etc. -> must be rewritten

The MVC model allows to (almost) easily replace the view part, if you want to migrate from JSP to Velocity or Thymeleaf but still in a web application

Comment: Yes, this is the Model:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:465c

This is the controller:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:465d

and this is the View (I didn't write any html, I accessed my application with URL ie http://localhost:8080/Application/Occurences,woord=dad&letter=d)
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:465e

For re-writing this into a Java application, I'd use the Model (OccurencesCounter.java) and I'd rewrite the view(OccurencesCounterApp.java)
I'd access OccurencesCounter from the App class.